# How to create PDF bookmarks from Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf

I have a PDF file which I converted From Microsoft Word. Actually I'm working on an eBook and now I want to publish it as a PDF.

How do I create PDF bookmarks, either through Word or through editing the PDF afterwards?

Comment: @DOK :) can u plz merge my question

Comment: Have you got Acrobat Pro?

Comment: @slotishtype:) no ...

Comment: I added a new answer, hope this works for you.

Comment: Can anyone update with Microsoft 2016 and 2019 screenshots?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is another solution for word 2007.

1) Install the pdf/xps add-on from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=4d951911-3e7e-4ae6-b059-a2e79ed87041&displaylang=en).

2) Go to Save as in your word file (which already has a number of headings outlined).

3) Save as PDf or XPS.

4) Click on the options button on the save as dialog.

[image: options save as dialog]

5) Check the "Create bookmarks using" checkbox.

[image]

6) Click OK.

7) click publish.

This will give you headings as bookmarks in the pdf.

Comment: ) now i want to know how to design an pdf file? like so many book have an design in pdf?

Comment: Have you got Indesign?

Comment: This option is built-in in Word 2016.

Comment: Can anyone update with Microsoft 2016 and 2019 screenshots or are they the same?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Acrobat 9 professional, you can use the original word outline (chapter and headings) as bookmarks in your PDF document.

Here is a [tutorial](http://mydocs.epri.com/docs/CorporateDocuments/WorkingWithEPRI/CreatingAcrobatPDFs.pdf).  On page 8, there is a section  on "Creating a PDF with Automatic Bookmarks"

Comment: ) i have only adobe reader x then ?

Comment: slotishtype:) u thr

Comment: Yes.  What version of word have you?  I might be wrong but I think you need pro to create pdfs.

Comment: Word doesn't have a "Pro" version I know of. Word 2007 and Word 2010 can export directly to PDFs with bookmarks/outlines (or there are MS-provided addons to enable this feature).

Comment: I meant acrobat reader pro... Not word pro.

Answer (score 1):

Just an update to the other answers...

in case you are **on Office 2013**, you have to click on "Export" instead of "Save as"

and then you will find the options to add bookmarks based on the different "levels" inside the document.

Comment: Same applies to **Office 2016** as well.