# Add or delete bookmarks - Word

Tags: microsoft-word

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create PDF bookmarks from Microsoft Word?](https://superuser.com/questions/293968/how-to-create-pdf-bookmarks-from-microsoft-word)

how to create msword bookmarks, Actually I have an ebook now i want to add Bookmarks in that File how it is possible ?

Comment: I answered your previous question. Please see http://superuser.com/questions/293968/how-to-create-pdf-bookmarks/293981#293981. Also, could you make your questions a little clearer.

Comment: Please don't double-post. Extend your other question instead. You already asked how to create bookmarks there, maybe just add that you're using Word.

Comment: @slhck:) when i m unable to add bookmarks in PDF then after my new question generate but right now i have an ans for PDF but see my comment !! and also this question is completely different this question is for word only

Comment: why -ive voting? is it not a gud question

Comment: @User You could rephrase your other question to say "How to create PDF bookmarks from Word", then you wouldn't need that one. If you don't get the right answer, don't open a new question, but edit your old question instead to be more precise. You only have *one* problem to solve, namely creating an eBook from Word.

Comment: There, I edited [your old question](http://superuser.com/questions/293968/how-to-create-pdf-bookmarks-from-microsoft-word). That should get you the answer you were looking for, or not?

Answer (score 1):

In Word 2010, you would need to select text, or click where you want to insert the bookmark.

Then, from the Insert tab (on top), go in the Links group and click Bookmark.

Next, under Bookmark name, type the name of the bookmark.

Finally, click Add.

More info here:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/add-or-delete-bookmarks-HP001226532.aspx#BM1